# Why is there an exception when forming 3rd conjugation imperatives?

Tags: verbs, conjugation, imperative

All of the affirmative singular imperatives of regular verbs are formed by dropping the *-re* from the second principal part.
Why is it that, in the 3rd conjugation only, the affirmative plural imperative drops the *-ere* from the second principal part and then adds *-ite* instead of just dropping the *-re* and adding *-te* like in the other conjugations?

Answer (score 4):

This has to do with the verbal conjugation system of Proto-Indo-European (PIE), the ancestor language of Latin. The Latin third conjugation is largely descended from so-called "thematic" PIE verbs. Thematic verbs are those which have a vowel, either *e* or *o*, between the verb root and the ending; this is known as the "thematic vowel". In this case, the vowel was *e*, so the 2pl. imperative would have ended in *-e-te*. This *e* later changed into Latin *i* by the regular sound change of "vowel reduction", in which basically all short vowels in non-initial open syllables changed into *e*.

It's not only the *i* of *-ite* that is descended from the PIE thematic vowel, but also the *i* that shows up elsewhere in the third conjugation present forms: *ag-i-s, ag-i-t*, etc.

(The other three conjugations, too, mostly continue PIE thematic verbs, but in those conjugations the thematic vowel eventually merged into the long vowel of the verb stem.)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is due to vowel reduction. Latin vowel reduction is complicated and there seem to be various processes involved; however, a common pattern is vowels turning to /i/.

*Syllable and Segment in Latin,* by Ranjan Sen (2015), describes a process called "[Archaic Latin vowel reduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VTCBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA80&lpg=PA80&dq=Latin%20vowel%20reduction&source=bl&ots=ZWsyUWxsZM&sig=FYvfZNv1EvETxEo_Tpq7L07FDj8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihgJeD5b3QAhWIrlQKHTJiB24Q6AEIYjAL#v=onepage&q=Latin%20vowel%20reduction&f=false)" whereby short vowels in internal (not initial or final) open syllables were generally all merged to a reduced vowel which became /i/ in Classical Latin. In internal open syllables before /r/, however, the reduced vowel became /e/ instead. This explains the difference between *-**i**te* and *-**e**re.*

I don't know what the original vowel was in third-conjugation verbs, but it seems like we would get this pattern no matter what it was. It seems to come from the Proto-Indo-European "thematic vowel" (for example, see this page from [Allen and Greenough](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/present-stem)) which apparently could be -e- or -o-. I don't understand the details of its distribution; however, the -u- that appears in Latin verbs of the third declension before nasals in closed syllables (e.g. in third-person plural *-**u**nt*) seems to descend from PIE -o-.